# Get a parameter of a job in Hangfire job filter when Job Failed

Tags: c#, hangfire

In order to send emails when job fails I'm trying to implement something like this : [Hangfire send emails after retry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62644191/hangfire-send-emails-after-retry) .

But I need to access a parameter of the job method performed. This parameter corresponds to an ID of a company, and I need this idea in order to know which connectionString should i use to access db.

I need to access a DB here to know if we have already sent an email for the current job (in order to not spam emails everytime the same job fails).

So i would have something like this :

- Job A Runs
- Job A Fails
- Job A Filter is executed,

  - Job A Filter Check in db if email has been already sent for this job

    - If not send an email to admins
    - Put a record in db to indicate that an email has been sent for this job
- Job A Runs
- Job A Fails
- Job A Filter is executed again

  - Job A filter won't send an email because it has been already sent
    Etc...

I don't know if it's the correct approach to go for, if you guys have any idea to improve that, feel free !

But still, my question is can i access to a parameter of the executed job method to know that company id ? Or is there any way to provide datas from job method to an AttributeFilter (like bags etc...) when a job fails to execute?

Thanks for reading me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this with an `IApplyStateFilter`

```
public class NotifyExceptionsServerFilter : IApplyStateFilter
{
    public void OnStateApplied(ApplyStateContext context, IWriteOnlyTransaction transaction)
    {

        var c = context.NewState as FailedState;
        if (c?.Exception != null && context.Job.Method.Name == "YourMethodName")
        {
            var companyId = context.Job.Args[CompanyIdArgumentIndexInYourMethodSignature];

            // Do stuff using CompanyId
        }
    }

    public void OnStateUnapplied(ApplyStateContext context, IWriteOnlyTransaction transaction)
    {
    }
}
```

This is roughly the idea. Would it work, it will need at least to be secured with specific tests preventing errors caused by refactoring, as it relies on Reflection.

Comment: Good to know ! I have a question though. Here the CompanyIdArgumentIndexInYourMethodSignature is something that i can get somewhere ? Or I have to put it myself as long as i know the method signature. Because if i could get that index by using reflection (so get the index of the parameter by name parameter),  that would be great. Because i can't really hard code the index, as long as it can be sometimes 2, sometimes 3 etc... But what i'm sure of is that argument will always have the same name companyId. Is there any way to get it with this informations ? thanks by the way !

Comment: @ZeniFlow you can get the method parameters, and thus their indexes, with `context.Job.Method`  which is a `MethodInfo`, and its method `GetParameters`.